# How could I hear a sound from one VSE in another

Tags: camera, video-sequence-editor, scene, audio

Start up a new blend file.

1. Go into VSE
2. Add audio
3. Add another new scene (in the same file)
4. Go into VSE of this new scene.
5. Add a scene strip of the first scene

But you can't hear the audio from that VSE Scene Strip.
How do I fix that?

- If I change *Scene > Input* from *Camera* to *Sequencer*, it plays the audio, but it does not show the camera view.
- If I add the same scene strip and I set Input > Camera, the sequence doesn't work either.

[image: this is the default View. It shows the camera Output but You cant hear Audio]

[image: This is the Sequence View. It Plays Audio but it Does not Show The Camera View]

I'm not that good in Blender, I just started this year.

My Blender Version is. 3.2.0

My PC specs are

Lenovo Chromebook 300E 4GB RAM 32GB

Comment: you can ask as many questions as you want - that's totally fine. But...you should provide all (!) necessary informations, which you didn't. So please provide the blend file so we can check it out. Thx. Also please tell us your blender version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario where ...

- **Scene A** containes audio strip in VSE and
- **Scene B** with *Scene A* strip placed in this VSE.

Hmm, same for me ... if Scene A is Input > Sequencer it plays (and shows correctly what is in VSE, that cant be current 3D Viewport), scene strip duplication make strip silent ...

... it sounds to me like a bug (or could be called a current limitation by devs) ... so the only way that came to my mind (that worked for me) is to **add Speaker** object into *Scene A* into *3D Viewport* :)

Note: similar (not the same, but probably related to each other) issue on [bug tracker](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109557#issuecomment-1093040).

- If you are experiencing audio lag go to *Timeline Editor > Playback > Sync Audio* https://imgur.com/WYFhY8e
- For video lag search for *cache* (proxy works only foe sequence or movie not for scene strip).

Comment: Any problem to test it out? BTW comment section is not allowed for chatting. What about delete ours previous comments ... Thanks